# As a EU citizen, are there any low-effort diversification options that could protect me against inflation or a local crisis?

Tags: european-union, legal, deposits, security, diversification

The recent political events in the EU and in my own country (Poland) led me to reconsider my current saving scheme and I'm looking for a low-effort way to diversify what I have in order to better protect it against the aftermath of local inflation or a country-wide crisis.

My initial idea was to set up a bank account somewhere beyond its borders, hoping that would mean it's also beyond political reach of my country. This would also involve storing the value in a different currency, which could potentially make sense because in my scenario I don't assume an entire continent going bankrupt so EUR would still be at least valuable. The problem is that I don't know how to start with this and whether this actually gives me any advantage.

For example, let's say I chose BNP Paribas and decided to try to open their account outside of Poland. If a major part of money stored in Polish accounts got wiped just like it happened in Greece, would I be protected? Is it even possible to open such an account in the EU without being a citizen of the country I want to open a bank account in? And if my reasoning is incorrect, is there any other low-effort way to better protect against the problem that doesn't involve learning how to trade stocks?